# Get MAC address in Flint OS

Tags: pi-3, networking, operating-systems

I'm relatively new to Raspberry Pi in general, my basic experience is with loading XBMC or Noobs.

I've got a project with work that I'd like to utilize Raspberry Pi as a terminal which only needs a web browser. I've installed Flint OS (other recommendations are welcome). The operating systems seems to be what we need, but our network requires validation of the MAC address.

Is there a way to get this from Flint OS?

I've tried using Ctrl+Alt+F2 as is available in older versions of Chromium OS, but it crashes Flint every time. Also, I am currently connected via WiFi which is the only reason I need the MAC address.

Comment: Have you tried getting it from your router?

Comment: I have not. But I do not have administrative rights, so I'll need to bring it up with the boss. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'd maybe be just a little cautious about using a [3 month old](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlintOS/comments/58tmkh/where_do_i_download_it/d9kmuq0/?st=izhn9tf7&sh=1c225473) OS fork for something at work. Exciting new toys tend to exhibit exciting new behaviours until they get past the teething troubles. Are there specific features that would rule out core chromium (which would let you access the terminal again)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please type ctrl+alt+t from your browser window. This opens the crosh terminal.
crosh>

Now, type 'shell' (without the quotes). You will have access to bash and can do whatever you wanted to with the ctlrl+alt+f2.

The system currently freezes with ctrl+alt+f2. Press ctrl+alt+f1 to get back to the GUI.